# Javascript change Object structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, underscore.js

My object looks like this:

```
{34: true, 35: false}
```

How do I convert the Object to be exactly like this Array:

```
[{id: 34, _destroy: '1'}, {id: 35, _destroy: '0'}]
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Object cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: You have to use very powerful magic.

Comment: I have edited the question, please check again :) thanks

Comment: like this: `Object.keys(o).map(function(el){ return {id:el, _destroy: o[el]?'1':'0'}; })`

Comment: @Grundy I like your approach.

Comment: Bah @Grundy that's way better than mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function convertIt(obj) {
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        var convertedObjs = [];    
        keys.forEach(function(key){
              var destroy = obj[key] ? "1" : "0";
              convertedObjs.push({"id": key, "_destroy" : destroy  });
        });
        return convertedObjs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you guys think about this?

```
var myObject = {34: true, 35: false}
var result = [];
underscore.each(myObject, function(v, k) {
  result.push({id: k, _destroy: v ? '1' : '0'})
});

console.log(result);
> [{id: 34, _destroy: '1'}, {id: 35, _destroy: '0'}]
```

Comment: i think not need use 3rd party lib where you can use plain js :-)